# What is the best way to compare 2 records and find differences between each pair of properties?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-6.0

I am using `record` from C# 9, for example

```
public record Receipt
{
    public string ClientName { get; init; } = "";

    public string ClientPhoneNumber { get; init; } = "";

    public List<OtherRecord> OtherInfo { get; init; } = new();
}
```

and would like a function to compare 2 instances of that type and return a list of all values that are not identical on both sides (for auditing purpose).

I suppose it would use reflection so it can support any record type, without hardcoding the properties names?

Comment: records do that automatically - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality

Comment: @pm100 yes but I want to know more than just if the 2 instances are equal

Comment: i missed that, yes reflection is the way to go

Comment: things will get nasty for non primitive fields (like OtherInfo in your example)

Comment: @pm100 maybe...however all fields are either primitive or another record or a list of other records, and all records have only primitive fields or other records like that. So it's still a relatively simple model, it all eventually ends up to primitives.

Comment: so you have to do recursize descent to compare, might be interesting to look at what c# generates fro simply comparing 2 records, does it do a deep compare?

Comment: Just putting this out there, for something quick and dirty when debugging, you could use a JsonSerializer on both records, and just leverage your existing diff viewer. E.g. if you have some deep & complex object structure produced by 2 different methods, and you'd like to see how the outputs differ.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects

I have found this to be excellent (I am in no way linked to the author or the project)